# php regex to get string within string of md code block

Tags: php, regex, string, full-text-search

I have this string:

````
```yaml
project_id: 524
type:
  - content changes
  - code changes
production_urls:
  - http://produrl.net/special/page
database_tables:
  - content
  - articles
```
````

I need to get the text in between `yaml` and ```. So the new string would start with `project_id...` and end with `...articles`

What is the most efficient way to get the new string with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regex, just do this:

````
<?php
$string = '```yaml
project_id: 524
type:
  - content changes
  - code changes
production_urls:
  - http://produrl.net/special/page
database_tables:
  - content
  - articles
```';

$string = preg_replace('#^```yaml(.*)```$#s', '$1', $string);

echo "<pre>".print_r($string, true)."</pre>";
?>
````

Comment: this will do it